# Teradata Python Package: How to access table in a non-default database in Teradata

Tags: python, teradata

Does Teradata Python provide a functon for user to access tables or views in a non-default database in Teradata?

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with a table present in non-default database user can do following:

Approach 1:

```
from teradataml.dataframe.dataframe import in_schema
df = DataFrame(in_schema("schema_name", "table_name"))
```

Approach 2:
Use Fully qualified table name

```
from teradataml.dataframe.dataframe import DataFrame
df = DataFrame.from_table("mydb.mytable")
```

Approach 3: 
Using from_table() and fully qualified table name.

```
from teradataml.dataframe.dataframe import in_schema
df = DataFrame.from_query("SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable")
```